# How can I insert a HTML tag before its parent tag using the Transformer from Genshi?

Tags: trac, transformer-model, genshi

I need to modify the file table in my trac browser view by creating a class which implements the `ITemplateStreamfilter` class. I tried using the `Transformer` from `genshi.filters.transform`. My table looks like

`<tbody>

    <tr class="even">

        <td class="name">

            <a class="partent" title="Parent Directory" ..>..</a>

        </td>

        ..

    </tr>

    ..

</tbody>`

I now need to insert a `</td>` tag just before the frist cell in the first row of the table. The problem is that I only can identify the position of column where I want to put the new cell befor by searching for the *"Parent Directory"* title: `Transformer('//*[@title="Parent Directory"]')`.  How can I step one tag up than put the new cell before the first `<td class="name">` tag?

Comment: did you try it with http://genshi.edgewall.org/wiki/ApiDocs/genshi.filters.transform#genshi.filters.transform:Transformer:prepend ?

Comment: Yes, I tried it for hours. With all these methods I can only insert data before, in or after the current tag. But I need my data one more tag above the current.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not THAT familiar with the support for `XPATH` of `Transformer` BUT:

What about 
`Transformer('(//td[*[@title="Parent Directory"]])[1]')` and then using the `before` method?

As far as I understand, this should select the **first** `td` node with a child node with an attribute `title="Parent Directory"`.

If you want to select **any** `td` with that kind of child node use
`Transformer('//td[*[@title="Parent Directory"]]')`

However, this only works **if** `Transformer` supports those `XPATH` expressions.

**Edit 1**

If you're sure, your `td` has an attribute `class="name"` you can also use `Transformer('(//td[class="name" and *[@title="Parent Directory"]])[1]')`

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried your suggestions but the transformer does not accept an embed XPATH expression. What I did so far is `Transformer('//tr[@class="even"]/td[@class="name"][1]').before(tag.td())` which puts the tag where I want it, but for all rows with `class="even"`. It seems that the occurence selection `[0]` does not work either. Is there another way to tell the Transformer to only select the first occurence?